# Nashorn : how to evaluate scripts in scripting mode

Tags: nashorn

Im starting to explore jdk 8 new javascript engine nashorn and wanted to build some automating task scripts. I ve an issue, ive no idea how to evaluate a js file in scripting mode from javascript, using engine.eval() eg .

p.s: im not talking about jjs -scripting which is good but only works one way. I want the other way; make the engine evaluate in scripting mode from java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching, i came up with a trick where i can actually launch my script's execution through a command line from a hand crafted System Process :

```
//tricking the nashorn engine with jjs command
    public void evalScriptInScriptingMode(String fileName)
    {
        String[] args = new String[]{"jjs", "-scripting", fileName};

        //This class is used to create operating system processes
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);

        pb.directory(null);

        File log = new File("jjs_log.txt");

        int i = 0;

        while(log.exists())
        {
            i++;
            log = new File("jjs" + i + "_log.txt");
        }


        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(log));
        Process p = null;

        try
        {
            p = pb.start();    //start the process which remains open
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add -Dnashorn.args=-scripting to you java command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to the script engine via the NashornScriptEngineFactory.

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory

new NashornScriptEngineFactory()
    .getScriptEngine( "-scripting" )
    .eval( "" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine("-scripting");` which will retrieve a new Nashorn ScriptEngine in scripting mode. This method is slightly better than using a System Process mainly because this automatically adds you classes to the nashorn classpath.

Basically, you can program classes in java and then use'em in javascript. If you do not need to be able to reference your classes in javascript then the System Process should do just fine and there won't be problems, ( if the machine on which this is running has jjs in their classpath )